# GatsbyJS and Contentful with SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I am looking to host a gatsbyjs blog that fetches data from Contentful similiar to the below example.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-contentful

Now, I would like to implement Server Side Rendering to my react blog.  However, I am not sure what changes do I need to make to the gatsby-ssr.js and gatsby-browser.js to get this magic happen.

PS:  I have gone through a handful of SSR with gatsbyjs examples but they did not help.  And I am new to React SSR.

Please let me know in case of any further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gatsby does SSR automatically for you as part of the build process.

When you run `gatsby build` the site (HTML/CSS/JS) is built for you and outputted to the "public" directory.

Try going through the official tutorial to learn more about how Gatsby's SSR process works.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/

Comment: I will try to run gatsby build and let you know the results.  I am actually having an issue running gatsby build as it throws an error.  I have opened another thread regarding the same.  Would really appreciate if you could help me onthat thread as well

Comment: Is this still correc, though? According to the doc on [Rendering Options](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/rendering-options/) the default rendering method is Static Site Generation (SSG) and [SSR](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/rendering-options/using-server-side-rendering/) appears to have its own section with extra steps to take. Or is this new with v4...?